# Hive performance to create Dashboard using Tableau?

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, tableau-api

We are planning to implement a project in Azure cloud where data storage will be Azure Data lake for now and in future HDP will be implemented and ADLS will be the extended datanode. From ADLS we want to expose data for Dashboard creation using Tableau. Initial plan was to use Hive and Tableau will connect to Data through Hive. But here comes the performance issue as:

1. There will be multiple users who will have access to Data through Tableau(100+)
2. We will also have to expose Data to different portal with API calls.

Which means multiple connectivity will be established at the same time which will hit hive . My question is:

1. Can hive serve the purpose with minimal time?
2. How can i measure the performance?
3. I dont want to let my users to sit back after running a query in tableau and wait for a long time to see the dashboard.

Would you please share your experiences in this design issue? Should we use Hive or should We use some other tools which have better performance to work with tableau and HDFS storage. Someone suggested me to use Azure SQL Server and connect Tableau to SQL server. But its again the old fashion and also matter of cost as price is related with the execution of each query.

If you have any better solution experience please share , would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive LLAP could work, if you can get it installed.

Otherwise, at my work, we've had good experience with PrestoDB and Tableau on S3 data.

Some teams use Spark SQL, and you can setup a Spark Thrift Server, that should be compatible with the Hive JDBC/ODBC drivers

Comment: Hi @ cricket_007, Thanks for jump-in. I do appreciate your suggestion. I want to try all of the 3 options and want to measure performance for the final go-ahead. For that I am planning to develop a POC for each of these. Would you please share experience with any performance testing tools that I can use to measure the performance ? That will be a great help too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, there is **TPC-DS benchmark** (which most SQL databases/tools use) or **YCSB**... But query performance widely varies on your actual data and hardware and query patterns (lots of joins, how you store the data, etc)